# How to check if string has vowels?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I tried to write a function which checks if a given string contains vowels and I cannot see why it works for some words 'cat' and 'why' but not 'DOG', i believe that i have accounted for uppercase.

```
const containsVowels = string => {

  var lowerCase = string.toLowerCase();
  var word = lowerCase.split("");
  var vowelsArray = ["a","o","i","u","y"];

const result = word.filter(letter => vowelsArray.includes(letter));

return result.includes("a","o","i","u","y");
```

};

Comment: try returning result only

Answer (score 2, accepted):

2 Problems,

Why would you use includes twice ?
&
You cannot use includes like

```
result.includes("a","o","i","u","y");
```

includes only accepts 2 param:
includes(searchElement, fromIndex)
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes

By filtering, you already know the result.
What you should do is, compare the length of the result:

```
const containsVowels = string => {
    let lowerCase = string.toLowerCase();
    let word = lowerCase.split("");
    let vowelsArray = ["a","o","i","u","y"];
    const result = word.filter(letter => vowelsArray.includes(letter));
    return result.length > 0 ? true : false
};
```

Answer (score 3):

`includes` takes only 2 parameters, the first one being `searchElement` and second parameter being `fromIndex`.

Reference : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes#parameters

You wouldn't want to do the last check if the result array contains vowels or not, because in the previous step itself you are filtering out the word to get array that contains only vowels. So just check if the array is empty or it contains any elements inside it.

```
const containsVowels = str => {
    let lowerCase = str.toLowerCase();
    let word = lowerCase.split("");
    let vowelsArray = ["a","o","i","u","y"];
    const result = word.filter(letter => vowelsArray.includes(letter));
    return result.length > 0;
};
console.log(containsVowels("cat"));
console.log(containsVowels("DOG"));
console.log(containsVowels("BCDF"));
```

**Suggestion:** Don't use built in keywords as variables.

As pointed out by Muhammad, we can regex to find if the string contains vowels

```
const containsVowel = str => {
 const vowelRegex = /[aeiou]/i;
 return vowelRegex.test(str);
};
```

Comment: You can go with regex that will be faster than Array.filter

Comment: Updated answer with regex support

Answer (score 1):

use regex to get the result.

```
var regEx = /[aeiou]/gi
var test_string = "Cat";
var match = test_string.match(regEx)

if(match)
  console.log("Match found", match)
```

Answer (score 0):

**when you write something like this**

```js
result.includes("a","o","i","u","y")
```

this compare with only it's first element which is "a" and one thing you don't need to write the above mentioned code further.
**After filtering just replace the above code with**

```js
return result.length > 0 ? true : false
```